# Strange ordinary differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

I am new to the world of differential equations. I found this strange one on a PDF online. The excercise itself says that "Wolfram-Alpha won't help" and I cannot find any explanatory solution of it. Can you help me?

The equation is the following:

$$4y^3+7x\sin(x)+4x^4-\left(-\frac 74y^2+16\cos(y)-7x\right)\frac{dy}{dx} = -e^{-x+y}+\sinh(y)$$

Edit: I found it at this link ([PDF](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~bruin/ODE-exercises-SoSe2016.pdf)). The exercise is the number 14.
Actually, it only says "Challenge Task: solve the following differential equation"

Thank you,
Dave

Comment: I'm curious to see where you found it. Looks strange indeed...

Comment: See, there is a catch: an exercise might be asking you to do a whole lot of things with a differential equation _other than solving it_. What does it ask, really?

Comment: I've added the link and the references of the problem. It doesn't says anything specific, only to solve it.

Comment: Considering that the Elite task is to prove Navier-Stokes problem, I sorta believe that this problem is just a joke to illustrate that differential equations are very hard.

Comment: If this is a joke, I'm very relieved! As a matter of fact, it seems like someone just put functions randomly in it...

Comment: Bad joke for sure !

Comment: I tried to solve it by an integrating factor but the algebra got too crazy that I gave up.